# How to build a executable JavaFX 11 application

Tags: java, maven, javafx, java-11, javafx-11

### Problem

I can't create "JavaFX Application" Artifact on IntelliJ IDEA, It
gives " 'javafx:deploy' is not implemented in this SDK." error.

I don't want to use Maven/Gradle because;
With Maven: I can't use my local jar library, I tried including as a lib, using Jitpack, Adding something in POM but none of them worked.
With Gradle: I don't understand Gradle, but I think it has same issue with maven (local libraries).
So I need a solution without Maven/Gradle.

#### Details

I tried creating "JAR Application" Artifact and built it but it doesn't run with double click or console command. I am sure I installed and configured JavaFX & jmods correctly.

#### What I want

Build an JavaFX executable, which runs without needing console command.

#### System Properties

- OS : Windows 10 21H1
- IDE : IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2021.1.3
- JDK & JavaFX SDK version : 11
- I use FXML and Scene Builder (embedded into IDE)
- ***Project has Multiple Classes and Scenes.***

Comment: With Gradle, if I recall correctly, to declare a dependency on a local JAR file you simply need to do something like `implementation(file("path-to-jar"))` in the dependencies configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a solution without Gradle/Maven but I highly recommend you try using Gradle. Create a new Gradle Project (very easy if you use IntelliJ), and you only need to add dependencies in the build.gradle file. Example of what I use to make a Gradle Project using JavaFX :

```java
plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in java.
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is used by the application
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1')
    testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1')

}

run {
    standardInput = System.in
}

application {
    mainClass = "com.Nephty.main"
}

javafx {
    version = "15.0.1"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls' , 'javafx.fxml' , 'javafx.media' ]
}
```

Two important points : repositories, application and javafx.

In repositories, you specify the repository from which you want to download the librairies, so you don't have to keep them on your local machine. This helps sharing your program, as another user won't have to download and setup JavaFX himself (this can be impossible for a non tech-savy).

In JavaFX, you specify the modules you want to use and the version.

In application, you specify your main class which will be ran.

Then, you can do a console command : graldew.bat run (with cwd as your project directory) or use the easily accessible task in IntelliJ. After that, you can create a shortcut that will automatically run the console command without needing you to open the console and type everything out. If you are the only who is going to use your application, this is the same as having an executable (if we only care about using the program).

There is an application that helps building executable files for java application. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fD9q9-QrM8) video explains it.

Hopefully you can find what you're looking for here. If not, don't mind replying so we can try to figure something out.

Comment: @Voltaire If you do end up using Gradle you may want to look into the [badass-jlink-plugin](https://badass-jlink-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/) to make it easier to create executables via `jpackage` (that assumes you're using a Java version which includes `jpackage`, i.e. Java 14+). Packaging with `jpackage` is typically preferred over an executable JAR file, especially for JavaFX.

Comment: Also, some clarifications: You should only need `run { standardInput = System.in }` if you plan on using `System.in` for user input within your application, which is atypical in GUI applications. The Guava and JUnit Jupiter dependency declarations are not _necessary_, but obviously keep them if you use them. And keep in mind that Gradle is a development tool and does not exist for your application after deployment; so while Gradle definitely makes dependency management easier you still need to ship dependencies with your application (`jpackage` can make this easy).

Comment: Thank you for the info, I didn't know if I could actually remove this line. Also, I use Gradle for development and if I want to send the application to my friends, they can just run it using Gradle, because they're a bit tech-savies. Though I never thought about a broader (more broad ?) deployment, jpackage might come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

Just go for jpackage. Here is the link to the documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A